# why got a nullpointexception when one instance of message called many times sendtotarget

Tags: android, message

my message  call sendtotarget to update view to “loading“ when service   is start load data from server, i call again sendtotarget for update view where service loaded data from server , but a nullpointexception happening.

```
this.message = message;
    message.what = BaseService.START_LOADING;
    message.sendToTarget();

List<FriendDTO> friendDTOs = FriendProvider.gson.fromJson(resJsonObject, collectionType);
    message.what = BaseService.SUCCESS;
    message.obj = friendDTOs;
    message.sendToTarget();
```

Comment: Where is the NPE thrown?

Comment: When you call "FriendProvider.gson.fromJson" this might return null  in case the json string is null. There is a possibility of getting NPE due to that. Refer this link for more info: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.Class-

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException                        
 at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:360)